# Fixed web page width for mobile devices

Tags: android, html, css, mobile

I've been working on a responsive design. To stop the content from crossing boundaries i've used **viewpoint meta tag with width = 480**. The problem is i want my **website to load with minimum of 480px** no matter what. If the screen width is less than 480px I want it to **fit the screen width** by "Zooming out".

I've used the following viewpoint meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=480px, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

I've also used min-width css tag to specify minimum width.

```
<body style="min-width: 480px; width:100%; margin:auto;">
```

So after all this when i tried to load the website in DevTools Emulator (Google Chrome), it shows a horizontal scrollbar. Got any ideas on how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `width=device-width`?

I don't think forcing the 480px in the meta will do what you want (not crossing media-query-type boundries).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried using whdth=device-width. But the thing is it sets the width equal to device width. if the width of the mobile view of the site is less 480px the content of the page gets messed up. So i want it to redistrict min width to 480px

Comment: Can you use media-queries to target devices with width < 480px?
Example: [article on media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Comment: Additionally, without knowing exactly what type of mobile application or device you're developing, consider that having your code require that a device match **EXACTLY** a certain width is usually a bad idea. The reason being that tons of devices will not hit that exact measurement. Usually better to use device size ranges to single out a design.

Comment: If you can upvote my answer, or if it worked, accept the answer as correct that would be cool.